# Distinguish dots in a scatter plot according to coincidence in a column and in a list

Tags: python, seaborn

I have created a scatter plot using (as a model for this public question) the next df. And I have a list of names that match with one column of the data frame. I want to distinguish by color the names that match in both objects and the ones that are only in the df.

My df

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
'x': ["NameA", "NameB", "NameC"],
'y': [5, 15, 5],
'z': [1,2,3]
})

       x   y  z
0  NameA   5  1
1  NameB  15  2
2  NameC   5  3
```

The code to create the scatter plot looks like that

```
sns.set(rc={'figure.figsize':(11.7,8.27)})
sns.set_context('notebook')
sns.set(color_codes=True)
sns.scatterplot(data=df, x='z', y='y',
               color="g")
```

The list with names:

```
names = ["NameA","Namec"]
```

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: So, you want to colour all points for which `x` is in `names` with blue, for instance, and all others should be unchanged? Something like `df["IsInNames" ] = df.x.isin(names)` and then colour the scatter plot based on this column?

Comment: I would like to plot all names with the same color and then the names that match plot them with a different color (green, orange, blue) and put a legend.